# Are coded UI tests supported for Silverlight 5 in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, silverlight-5.0, coded-ui-tests

I would like to know if Coded UI tests are supported for Silverlight 5 in Visual Studio 2013. I have goggled a lot to fetch information about this issue but didn't get proper information.
Only the plugin for Silverlight 5 is available but the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.Silverlight reference is not available for Silverlight 5 projects. So i am unable to detect Silverlight controls of the application.

Comment: See http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/51b4a94a-1878-4dcc-81e0-7dc92131d2da

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I have added the plugin from the same link you mentioned but i didn't get the Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.SilverlightUIAutomationHelper reference for Silverlight 5 application,the existing reference applicable for only Silverlight 4 application.

Comment: The link I gave is for the Visual Studio 2013 version that claims to support Silverlight 5.0. Are you looking at the older version?

Comment: I am looking for Visual Studio 2013 with Coded UI to support Silverlight 5.

Comment: I wanted my Silverlight 5 Application to automate using Coded UI.For that i have downloaded 1)VS 2013 Premium 2)Silverlight add-on suppoting Silverlight 5 application. To add the reference to my CodedUI project i have added reference as mentioned in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg313838(v=vs.100).aspx#AddDll link. But still while recording silver light controls are not being detected. The reference mentioned in above link supports only silverlight 4 applications.

Comment: There have been two releases of Visual Studio since the 2010 instructions you are following. So interpret the old instructions carefully. There are additional notes on getting it to work on the Q&A and the Review pages of the link I gave.